# Spring JMS 4.3.2 + Jboss EAP 6.4.8 + Webmethods Jms Broker 8.2 + Durable shared topic subscription

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jboss-eap-6, jms-topic, webmethods

I'm trying to subscribe to a topic using durable and shared enabled, so that multiple instance can be connected to a topic to increase the scalability.
 However, only the first instance getting connected without any errors, the second instance message listener keeps throwing the below error messages. I checked with my Webmethods counterpart and he found that the client state was disabled and that's why second listener was not able to connect using the same subscription name.

Can someone throw light on this issue please.

> 18:14:15,050 WARN
>
> [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
>   (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-145) Setup of JMS message listener
>   invoker failed for destination 'topicName' - trying to recover. Cause:
>   [BRM.10.2209] JMS: Durable subscription
>   "connectionFactory##subscriptionName" is in use.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
JMS: Durable subscription "connectionFactory##subscriptionName" is in use.
```

typically hints at a misconfiguration of your Topic on Broker. Please check (with MWS) that the Topic really has "Shared State=true“:

[image]

Then make sure your Connection Factory has a „Connection Factory Client ID“ set:

[image]

And finally you should set the following JVM setting:

```
-Dcom.webmethods.jms.clientIDSharing=true
```